# Sum td with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<td  class="sum"><?php echo $item->get('unit_price') * $item->get('quantity'); ?></td>
<td  class="sum"><?php echo $item->get('unit_price') * $item->get('quantity'); ?></td>
<td  class="sum"><?php echo $item->get('unit_price') * $item->get('quantity'); ?></td>
<td  class="sum"><?php echo $item->get('unit_price') * $item->get('quantity'); ?></td>
<tr><td id="total"></td></tr>
```

I tag the TD with 'sum' and I use javascript like below:

```
<script>
var sum = 0;
$('.sum').each(function() {
        sum += sum;
});
$('#total').text(sum);
</script>
```

I know it does not work, I am new to Javascript.Thanks a lot!

Comment: try var sum = $('.sum').length

Comment: Replace your `sum = +sum;` by `sum++;`

Comment: @impaler what exactly do you want the result? the sum of value inside tag td or the number of td's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside of `each` loop you must take current value of the `td` (its innerText converted to Number) and add to `sum`:

```
var sum = 0;
$('.sum').each(function() {
    sum += Number($(this).text());
});

$('#total').text(sum);
```

Also you should add `colspan="4"` to `td#total` to make HTML valid.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7f0todr1/

Answer (score 1):

Should just be something like:

```
  // Gets the number of elements with class yourClass
  var totalTd = $('.sum').length;
  $('.total').text(totalTd);
```